# How can I create a GtkImage from a GIcon witha a fallback?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I have a Gio.Icon (or GIcon in C, I'm using pygobject). Right now I'm using the following code to create a Gtk.Image from the Gio.Icon:

```
image = icon and Gtk.Image(gicon=icon, icon_size=Gtk.IconSize.DIALOG, pixel_size=48, use_fallback=True)
```

The problem is, that the Gio.Icon isn't garanteed to have a valid icon name/path and when it doesn't it shows a broken image icon. I would like to fall back to using a different icon I know exists if the supplied Gio.Icon is invalid. Is there some way to know if the Gio.Icon is invalid, or if the Gtk.Image would show as a broken image?

**EDIT**

A minimal example:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)

icon = Gio.Icon.new_for_string('gnome-garbage')
fallback_icon = Gio.Icon.new_for_string('folder')
image = Gtk.Image(gicon=icon, icon_size=Gtk.IconSize.DIALOG, pixel_size=48)
win.add(image)

win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Try to load an invalid icon and check if that raises an exception. If that's the case, catch it and put your fallback code.

Comment: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/asking_for_permission_instead_of_forgiveness_when_working_with_files.html

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception, it just shows a broken image.

Comment: Even with `use_fallback=False`? Adding an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help too.

Comment: From the GtkImage documentation: 'If the file isn’t loaded successfully, the image will contain a “broken image” icon similar to that used in many web browsers.' And origionally I had use_fallback as False, and had the same problem. use_fallback just tells it split the icon name by hyphens and try to find a shorter name for which an icon does exist.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer in the [GtkImage documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkImage.html):

> If the file isn’t loaded successfully, the image will contain a “broken image” icon similar to that used in many web browsers. If you want to handle errors in loading the file yourself, for example by displaying an error message, then load the image with gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file(), then create the GtkImage with gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf().

Although, in my case I actually need to use a GtkIconTheme to get a PixBuf instead of `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file`:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)

def load_icon(icon):
    info = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().lookup_by_gicon(icon, 48, Gtk.IconLookupFlags.FORCE_SIZE)
    if info:
        return info.load_icon()

icon = Gio.Icon.new_for_string('gnome-garbage')
fallback_icon = Gio.Icon.new_for_string('folder')

pixbuf = load_icon(icon) or load_icon(fallback_icon)
image = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
win.add(image)

win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```